# htaccess file doesn't disable directory listing

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to disable directory listing on my website via the .htaccess file,
this is the current htaccess file that runs on my server: http://pastebin.com/eH0ZW7JB but directory listing is still on, as can be seen [here](http://mc-heads.net/assets/)

Comment: Does everything else in your .htaccess work? Maybe your main server configuration does not allow override.

Comment: Yep, everything else works just fine

Comment: Nginx **does not** support .htaccess.

Comment: [http://mc-heads.net/assets/](http://mc-heads.net/assets/) reports _Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at mc-heads.net Port 80_, but [http://mc-heads.net/](http://mc-heads.net/) says **nginx/1.9.9** ?

Comment: @IlliyaGolik There seems to be a conflict with two different web servers. Please resolve that condlict first. Based on dusan.bajic's comment.

Comment: @dusan.bajic yes, seems strange, might as well as well and an index file to every directory, instead of dealing with the shit shared host that i'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a .htaccess in the assets folder? If not, try adding a .htaccess file with just this in it:

```
Options -Indexes
```

After that, let us know. It could be another .htaccess file interfering or some other rules that are causing an issue.

Comment: I just tried that, i added an htaccess file to /assets/ with `Options -Indexes ` and it still show directory contents